# MVC Pass textbox to controller if not in a form tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on and Microsoft MVC3 project and cannot pass a parameter which has been edited to the controller. It will only pass back the original set parameter
For example:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("share file", InviteController.Actions.Result, InviteController.Name, new { message = Model.Message }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                UpdateTargetId = "popup",
                OnSuccess = "$('#popup').dialog('open')"
            }, new { id = "popup-button" })

<label>Personal Message <span class="optional-message">(optional)</span></label>
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message)
</div>
```

This will pass the to the following controller but the 'message' parameter has the original message and not the updated message:

```
 public ActionResult Result(FormCollection coll, string message)
    {
```

I'd love if someone could give me some advice.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a form instead:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    InviteController.Actions.Result, 
    InviteController.Name, 
    null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "popup",
        OnSuccess = "$('#popup').dialog('open')"
    }, 
    new { id = "popup-button" }))
{
    <label for="Message">
        Personal Message 
        <span class="optional-message">(optional)</span>
    </label>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message)
    <button type="sybmit">share file</button>
}
```

And don't forget that HTML forms cannot be nested. So if you have an outer form this won't work.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply I cannot do this as the personal message is page generic and I have other popups which will need this message value. It will be outside any form

Comment: You are welcome. Do you still have other questions on this subject?